# Android Studio Different project version handle

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to know how handle pro and lite version of my app in Android Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gradle build system used by Android Studio is specifically designed to make it easy to have multiple versions of your app -- developers who have a lite vs. pro version of their app was one of the main use cases that was considered.

It's done through having a single project with different *flavors* -- your app will have a lite flavor and a pro flavor. These flavors share the same code base and build files, but you can customize each flavor to have additional resources and code as necessary. When developing, you select which flavor you're working on via IDE GUI and can code, build, and run that flavor. At build time, you can choose to build just a single flavor or all flavors.

See the Gradle documentation at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants for more information, and search Stack Overflow for Gradle flavors to get some Q&A and examples of how it's used.

Comment: Thank Scott Barta its really help full .

Answer (score 1):

You can set flag (for single value or flag object for multiple values), and check the flag for lite version or pro version.

Another way is mentioned in [this](http://bartinger.at/organization-tips-for-android-projects/) link in detail.

**Edit**

I found an short info regarding build variant [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename).

Also, we can switch build variant using Android Studio menu

```
Build > Select Build Variant
```

Comment: Problem occurs when you need to upload same package name in google play for pro and lite.

Comment: @VasilValchev Sorry for the late. I found short info for changing build variant. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you two simple ways (depending on your app what is easier to implement and to support and how secure your app has to be -> illegal copying/sensual user data/etc.). I am not saying that these are the best ways out there but some easy once:

**First one:** just develope two different .apk -> e.g. MyAppPro.apk and MyAppLite.apk. To don't lose yourself withinthe different code: Both classes should have the same source code, except the ProVersion has got some EXTRA classes. It is easier to support and to fix bugs using the same sources (for bugs you will need only to correct them once) and extra classes for extra content.

**Second one:** I don't know about your applications functionallity. But if you using a server you can create kind of a database. Here you can save some identificcation number/ log-in data for every user using your app and add a parameter if the User is allowed to access Pro content or not. When trying to use Pro content you check if he is allowed or not. Keep in mind that this way requieres permanantly internet access.

As identification you can ask the theser to create an account (maybe a Name is enough, maybe you should better use an account with password... matters on what kind of app we are talking about). You can save these data on local storage of the devices and read them out everytime your app is started, so the user don't need to login everytime again, he wants to use your app.